# How can I get list of installed applications on mac os x programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, .app

How can I get installed apps in mac os x programmatically either through C code or Objective-C code?

Comment: that is ls command in terminal . I want to get list of installed apps  programmatically

Comment: do u want the list of apps only in ur Applications folder? or all the .app files in ur mac?

Comment: Is it possible to get all .app files in mac ?

Comment: yes it is. check the answer..

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to get all the app files using the spotlight API. Specifically, NSMetadataQuery class..

```
-(void)doAQuery {
    query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
   // [query setSearchScopes: @[@"/Applications"]];  // If you want to find applications only in /Applications folder

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kMDItemKind == 'Application'"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:nil];
    [query setPredicate:predicate];
    [query startQuery];
}

-(void)queryDidFinishGathering:(NSNotification *)notif {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i< query.resultCount; i++ ){
        NSLog(@"%@", [[query resultAtIndex:i] valueForAttribute:kMDItemDisplayName]);
    }
}
```

You have various other attributes, such as `kMDItemFSName`. More attributes can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html)

The terminal version of the above is:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemKind=Application'
```

Comment: Neither nor works on 11.5.2

Comment: Looks like `kMDItemKind ` is localized. I had success with `"kMDItemContentType == 'com.apple.application-bundle'"`