# Programmatically get list of installed programs on Mac OS using C#

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, .net-core-3.1

I am struggling to get the list of installed applications/programs on MacOS using visual studio 2019 c#.
Can anyone advise me  how I can get that?

Comment: Hi,I have written  the  program in c# for windows that is reading all the installed programs and version number and then exported it to .csv file. I am trying to achieve the same goal for macOS. I am using .NET Core 3.1. I can read the registry keys for windows as @OlivierRogier mentioned but what about MacOS. It has a different architecture.

Comment: Had you take a look for example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280878/how-can-i-get-list-of-installed-applications-on-mac-os-x-programmatically and https://gist.github.com/benbalter/3db34485f49006c60129 and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/list_the_installed_apps

Comment: I did look into the reference links but I guess the first one is using some different technology than c# and my apologies, I am not macOS expert so did not get the  second one  correctly, How I can make use of it and how I can setup MDM domain on macbook.

Comment: I'm not familiar with macOS, but maybe it seems (*Availability iOS 5.0+, macOS 10.7+, tvOS 10.2+*) you can use this HTTP API to get an XML result for processing. In this case, you can use [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient) and any XML Parser you like, and why not LINQ to XML.

Comment: Can any other expert help me on it?